# Laravel - store database value to variable in controller

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I'm trying to store a database value to a variable in a controller. But i'm getting this error "Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int", i know what it means but i don't know how to fix it.

What i want is that if user is banned, then change $banned to true and return it.

```
private function isBanned() {
    $banned = false;
    $getBanned = DB::table('Uzivatele')->select('banned')->where('id', Auth::id())->get();

    if ($getBanned == 1) $banned = true;

    return $banned;
}
```

Comment: Simply by `$getBanned->banned == 1` instead of `$getBanned == 1`. Anyway you should use `->first()` instead of `->get()` method, because you want to access only one user.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Comment: I'd suggest using this code as a middleware rather than a controller...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to set it directly you can do this way

```
   $getBanned = DB::table('Uzivatele')->where('id', Auth::id())
                 ->update(['banned' => true])->get();
```

if you want to check the user is banned or not then you can check like this.

```
private function isBanned() {
    $banned = false;
    $getBanned = DB::table('Uzivatele')->select('banned')->where('id', Auth::id())->first();

    if ($getBanned->banned == 1) $banned = true;

    return $banned;
}
```

Comment: I need to check if the user is banned, not to ban him.

Comment: Well its the same as what @Marcin Magdziarz wrote. But thanks anyway :)